# Delete last record/row from memsql table on condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, singlestore

I wanted to delete the last row from a table where a serial_num matches. We can order by transcation_date. I wrote the procedure below but am still getting a syntax error. Any idea?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `motor_dba`.`kp_field_track_delete_last_motor_history`(serial_num_in varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL) RETURNS void AS
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM motor_field_track_transaction_history
  WHERE serial_num=serial_num_in
  ORDER BY transaction_date  DESC
  LIMIT 1;
END;
```

The error I am getting is:

> SQL Error [1064] [42000]: Compilation error in function
> `motor_dba`.`kp_field_track_delete_last_motor_history` near line 5:
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'ORDER BY transaction_date  DESC LIMIT 1'

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use order by with limit.

You could use an example as the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `motor_dba`.`kp_field_track_delete_last_motor_history`(serial_num_in varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL) RETURNS void AS
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM motor_field_track_transaction_history
  WHERE transaction_date IN
       (Select * from motor_field_track_transaction_history
        where serial_num=serial_num_in
        ORDER BY transaction_date  DESC
        LIMIT 1);
END;
```

Let me know if that works.